# why rockeqmq pull message size always equals 32? i`m setPullBatchSize(500);

Tags: java, rocketmq

rocketmq: 4.9.6
rocketmq-java-sdk: 4.9.6
jdk: 1.8

Using DefaultLitePullConsumer, there are more than 10,000 messages in the queue that have not been consumed. In the case of setPullBatchSize(500), the number of messages obtained is 32.

[image]

`   String group = "group_test";

```
String topic = "topic_test";

DefaultLitePullConsumer consumer = new DefaultLitePullConsumer();

DefaultLitePullConsumerImpl impl;

void fillImpl() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<DefaultLitePullConsumer> cls = DefaultLitePullConsumer.class;
    Field field = cls.getDeclaredField("defaultLitePullConsumerImpl");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    impl = (DefaultLitePullConsumerImpl) field.get(consumer);
}

long maxOffset(MessageQueue queue) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<DefaultLitePullConsumerImpl> cls = DefaultLitePullConsumerImpl.class;
    Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("maxOffset", MessageQueue.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    return (long) method.invoke(impl, queue);
}

@Test
void test() throws MQClientException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException,
        NoSuchMethodException {
    fillImpl();

    consumer.setNamesrvAddr("192.168.1.10:9876");
    consumer.setConsumerGroup(group);
    consumer.subscribe(topic, (String) null);
    consumer.setMessageModel(MessageModel.CLUSTERING);
    consumer.setPullBatchSize(500);
    consumer.setPullThreadNums(10);

    consumer.start();

    boolean allowRun = true;

    while (allowRun) {
        long diff = diff();
        List<MessageExt> polled = consumer.poll();

        System.out.printf("diff: %d; size: %d%n", diff, polled.size());

        if (polled.size() > 32) {
            allowRun = false;
        }
    }

    assertFalse(allowRun);
}

public long diff()
        throws MQClientException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException {
    Collection<MessageQueue> queues = consumer.fetchMessageQueues(topic);

    long diff = 0;

    for (MessageQueue queue : queues) {
        OffsetStore store = consumer.getOffsetStore();
        // 当前偏移量
        long offset = store.readOffset(queue, ReadOffsetType.READ_FROM_MEMORY);
        // 最大偏移量
        long max = maxOffset(queue);
        diff += max - offset;
    }

    return diff;
}
```

`

I tried setting setPullBatchSize, setPullThreadNums and consumerManageThreadPoolNums=6400, defaultQueryMaxNum=8400 in rocketmq server broke.conf. All changes did not make the message size of a single pull larger than 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit broker.config

`maxTransferBytesOnMessageInMemory=2097152` 
`maxTransferCountOnMessageInMemory=256`
`maxTransferBytesOnMessageInDisk=262144`
`maxTransferCountOnMessageInDisk=64`